# Two divs sharing one border and hover:after bug

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need four boxes in the corners of the div. When hovering on some div, I want to `display:block` a hidden div in the middle, sharing one border with the box being currently hovered.

[Here is jsfiddle with my current solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bdobry/usj53j20/1/)

It almost works fine. However, there are some bugs regarding the corner area. I display there the block element with background using `:after`. It is to achieve the effect of one border for two elements.

**The problem:**

So in Chrome hovering that area gives some strange interlacing effect. Each mouse movement by 1px hides and shows content div. [You can see it here in action](https://gfycat.com/SmallCrazyFlounder)

In newest Firefox it seems to be ok, but in created jsfiddle there's some other bug which you can test yourself.

I'm using grey background just for better visualization of the problem. It is also suppose to work for box 1 for now. Tried some jQuery with mouseover and hover with no success.

**EDIT - Final solution:**

The most important thing was to set `pointer-events: none;` to `after` block element. Since I got some votes up [here's more advanced code on jsfiddle using SASS](https://jsfiddle.net/bdobry/usj53j20/9/)
, and here's using plain css:

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.box-content {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 13%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
}
.box:hover:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.box:hover p {
  z-index: 3;
}
.box p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 13px;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-one {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box-one:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.box-one:hover ~ .content-one {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.box-two {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.box-two:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box-two:hover ~ .content-two {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.box-three {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box-three:hover {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.box-three:hover ~ .content-three {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.box-four {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.box-four:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.box-four:hover ~ .content-four {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box box-one">
    <p>BOX NAME 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-two">
    <p>BOX NAME 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-three">
    <p>BOX NAME 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-four">
    <p>BOX NAME 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-content content-one"></div>
  <div class="box-content content-two"></div>
  <div class="box-content content-three"></div>
  <div class="box-content content-four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its your `z-index` that seems to be the problem. I think chrome works it fine actually and it should flicker because the way its been `z-index`. You need all your blocks to sit on the top block 1, 2, 3 and 4 of the content that pops in

Comment: I know `z-index` doesn't look pretty. It's a bit "hacky" way of achieve this effect, but it doesn't work any other way. For some reason `.box:after` has to have negative `z-index` and it breaks all logical order. EDIT: When I did it the way you explained, the paragraph inside `.box` was always covered by the background.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it is "flickering" is unrelated to the pseudo-element; it's because you are partially overlaying the `.box-content` element over the `.box` elements so, when you move your mouse, it is no longer hovering over the `.box` element that triggered the `.box-content` element to display, rather it is hovering over the `.box-content` element itself so it disappears. Move your mouse again and it's hovering over the `.box` element once more, triggering `.box-content` to display again. To fix this, simply add a `:hover` pseudo-class to the `.box-content` element, like so:

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.box:hover ~ .box-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
.box p {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.box-content {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 11%;
}
.box-content:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.box-content:hover {
  display: inline-block;
}
.box-two {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.box-three {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box-four {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>BOX NAME 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-two">
    <p>BOX NAME 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-three">
    <p>BOX NAME 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-four">
    <p>BOX NAME 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you do not wish `.box-content` to remain visible while hovering over it but not hovering over one of the `.box` elements then add the [`pointer-events` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `.box-content`, like so:

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.box:hover ~ .box-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
.box p {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.box-content {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 11%;
}
.box-content:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.box-two {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.box-three {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box-four {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>BOX NAME 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-two">
    <p>BOX NAME 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-three">
    <p>BOX NAME 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-four">
    <p>BOX NAME 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content"></div>
</div>
```

Note, though, that Opera Mini doesn't [support `pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) and IE only added support in v11.

Comment: I knew the "mechanism" behind that flickering and I was trying to reorder `z-index`, however current structure was the only that worked. I didn't think of your solution, it is easy and works perfect, thanks! Later on I changed the code a bit to make all boxes work, and I got flickering in Chrome again when hovering the edge... [Here's new code.](https://jsfiddle.net/bdobry/usj53j20/6/) Do you have an idea how what does that?

Comment: Looks like it could be a problem with the nesting but I don't know SCSS at all.

Comment: [CSS code here if you want](https://jsfiddle.net/bdobry/usj53j20/8/). It looks like the bug appears only in Chrome and Opera for Mac. Tested in other browsers and works fine (as well as in Chrome for Win).

Comment: OK, what's happening there is you've recreated the same problem; hover over a box and its pseudo element appears so your mouse is now hovering over that. When your mouse leaves the pseudo element to the part of the box's border that is overlapped by the content, you are hovering over the content so it disappears. Move your mouse again and you're hovering the box once more and the content appears. So, it looks like the `pointer-events` solution is the one you want.